# I am making a opposite letter encryption thingie

Tags: string, input, typeerror

[I am learning from  a python tutorial begginer on yt and I need help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzYnd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Instead of posting a link to the image, post your code and error you are getting in a text format

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very likely in the input you're using, not the code itself. You can only supply letters that are in the `letters` dictionary. If you attempt to input a character that is not in the dictionary, it will return None (hence your problem with NoneType).
Because you didn't supply us with the full dictionary and your attempted input which generated the error I can't possibly know if that's the problem, but as an example, if your dictionary doesn't have punctuation or capital letters, any word/sentence with those characters would lead to the problem you presented in the image.